# How to correctly set the constraints for an image in navigationBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, navigationbar

There are thousands of explanations for setting an image in the navigation bar but, IMHO, they all have the same problem: They use a fixed height for the `UIImageView`, but if you rotate the device the `navigationBar`-height reduces in size and the image is too high. I tried to solve this problem with constraints, but I failed:

```
let imageView = UIImageView( image: UIImage( named: "logo.png" ) )
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView

let height = NSLayoutConstraint(
  item: imageView, attribute: .height,
  relatedBy: .equal,
  toItem: self.navigationItem.titleView, attribute: .height,
  multiplier: 1, constant: 0
)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate( [ height ] )
```

It doesn't work in landscape mode!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to set constraints in this case. A title view for navigation controller has default constraints to be centered horizontally and vertically, with fixed width and height. So all you need to do is to set the frame size in your view did load

```
let imageView = UIImageView( image: UIImage( named: "aaa.png" ) )
var frame = imageView.frame
frame.size.height = 30
frame.size.width = 30
imageView.frame = frame
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Then add a listener to detect orientation change and change frame size accordingly.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    let imageView = self.navigationItem.titleView!
    var frame = imageView.frame
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        frame.size.height = 10
        frame.size.width = 10
    } else {
        frame.size.height = 30
        frame.size.width = 30
    }
    imageView.frame = frame
}
```

The result looks like this

[image]